# What's with 'to'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

In Act II of The Devil's Disciple by George Bernard Shaw, a character named Anderson says,

> You'll be surprised to find how like hate is to love.

I don't know if this is a dated usage of ''like'' because if you think about how we would say the second half of the sentence *how like hate is to love* today as a simple statement, we would probably say it like so: *Hate is very much like love* and NOT *Hate is very much like **to** love*.
So what's with the 'to' in G.B.Shaw's original phrasing then?

Comment: What did Shaw know, really? If he compares hate, not with love, but with *to love*, he obviously missed the email mandating parallelism. My point exactly.

Comment: Shaw clearly didn't have a clue!

Comment: Warning: I'm writing this as a note to myself. No one should be put through the torment of my grammtical analysis: In modern English when 'like' is used to express similarity, it functions as a preposition, which makes 'how like hate' a prepositional phrase with 'is' being the obvious verb of the how-clause, which leaves 'to like' the subject of the how-clause if we consider 'to' an infinitive marker that together with 'love' forms a couterpart to hate...

Comment: To continue my last comment: ...in which case the word order should be 'to find how like hate to love is', skeleton of how-clause being 'how like X Y is', identical to that of 'there you go'. But the word order is in fact 'how like hate is to love' and seeing as the how-clause is part of a statement not a question on its own, 'to love' cannot be a grammatical subject for the clause. Let's look at this objective clause again 'how like hate is to love'. It's actually not hard to see 'hate' is the subject of the clause, and 'to love' being the object, 'how like' would be predicative adjective?

Comment: @rhetorician Your version was so much clearer in terms of grammatical structure. If Shaw would have worded this way, it would have saved me so much distress.

Comment: @Jenny I parse the 'to' not as an infinitive maeker but as a preposition, and 'love' as a noun. You compare this _to_ that. I think it is the old-fashioned use of 'like' that is throwing things off.

Comment: Shaw should have worded the sentence as follows (if only to make it clearer): You'll be surprised to find how alike hate and love are.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I agree. Thanks, @Mitch

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a dated usage (the play is, of course, set in the 18th century). Compare the poem by Henry King (17th century) which begins "Like to the falling of a star..." No need to distress yourself or to find fault with GBS.

Comment: What does this sentence mean?

Comment: @Man_From_India Which sentence?

Comment: "You'll be surprised to find how like hate is to love." - this one.

Comment: @Man_From_India - "You'll be surprised to find how much alike hate and love are."